# How compatible are bootstrap 2 plugins with bootstrap 3 markup

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm about to start a new app using angular and bootstrap. There are angular ports of bootstrap's jquery dependent plugins, but only for v2. Does anyone with experience of bootstrap 2 & 3 know if, broadly speaking, v2 plugins should still work with bootstrap 3's markup (i.e. does bootstrap 3 stick to similar html and class conventions to bootstrap 2).

Answer (score 1):

As for me, Bootstrap 3 has worked 100% well with Bootstrap 2 markup. I have almost every single element, I can guarantee that Bootstrap 3 is compatible with BS2. If it isn't for you, just go to the Bootstrap 2 customizer and then select the missing element. Hope this answered your question!

Comment: I'm not sure how this is possible given the differences in grid class names alone

Comment: This is an answer to the opposite of the question I asked (I want to know if BS2 plugins work with BS3 markup & styles), but thanks anyway